# What's this called, and how do you do it mathematically?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

So, I'm teaching myself physics, and I have limited knowledge of calculus(I'm taking my first high-school class next semester in math). I'm attempting to calculate torque, but this is math, not physics... say I have an arbitrary vector, and a tangent vector. I want to get how much of that first vector is parallel to that tangent vector. I haven't the slightest clue what it's called, or how you do it mathematically. I imagine that there is some trigonometry involved, not sure how. An example would be if the two vectors were perpendicular, the result would be <0, 0>, and if they were exactly parallel, it would be either vector, and partially parallel would be anywhere in-between.

Comment: This should get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/dotprod/dotprod.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosine of the angle between vectors will be the proportion you are looking for.  $\text{Angle}=0^\circ$, then the cosine of the angle is $1$ ($100$ %).
$\text{Angle}=90^\circ$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then the cosine of the angle is $0$.
Angle in between, will give you the proportion between $0-100$ % you are looking for.
If angle is greater than $90^\circ$, the sign will change, this means it is a vector that is pointing to the opposite direction.